# AngularJS1 : ng-blur inside the ng-if

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I'm trying to use `ng-blur`. Below is my HTML code:

```
<div ng-if="CurrentStage==='SaveQuery'">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group row">
         <label class="col-sm-3 control-label text-right">Query Name</label>
         <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" ng-blur="performValidationQueryName()" ng-model="QueryName" ng-class="QueryNameError?'form-control validation_error':'form-control'" placeholder="Query Name" />
            <span ng-if="QueryNameErrorMsg!=''" class="errorMsg">{{QueryNameErrorMsg}}</span>
         </div>
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code for blur event call is:

```
$scope.performValidationQueryName = function () {
    if($scope.QueryName != null && $scope.QueryName != '') {}
};
```

The issue I'm facing is:

When `ng-if="CurrentStage==='SaveQuery'"` is there inside div, my `ng-model="QueryName"` is not getting updated. And with blur of the text, I get `$scope.QueryName = ""` with `performValidationQueryName` function.

If, I remove `ng-if="CurrentStage==='SaveQuery'"`, all things works perfectly and I get the value inside the `$scope.QueryName`.

How can I call `ng-blur` which is placed inside the div with an `ng-if` condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use object in your input model will solve your problem because it comes under ng-if as shown below,

**Template:**

```
<div ng-if="CurrentStage==='SaveQuery'">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
           <div class="form-group row">
                 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label text-right">Query Name</label>
                 <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <input type="text" ng-blur="performValidationQueryName(Query.Name)" ng-model="Query.Name" ng-class="QueryNameError?'form-control validation_error':'form-control'" placeholder="Query Name" />
                       <span ng-if="QueryNameErrorMsg!=''" class="errorMsg">{{QueryNameErrorMsg}}</span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="clearfix"></div>
             </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.performValidationQueryName = function (queryName) {
  if (queryName != null && queryName != ''){
    //do something..
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I currently follow the same approach. I want to know the reason behind, why angular model is not updated with blur if ng-is is there.

Comment: The **ng-if** is directive, like other directives will creates a child scope of model value comes under that. Not only ng-blur it will happen on any event under ng-if. You can refer this known issue in this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6038).

Comment: Thanks!! It seems like ng-if create its own scope when we declare it. So when I used ng-if, then scope becomes part of ng-if div and not our ng-app. Due to that reason, this thing is not working. Moreover instead of using ng-if we can use ng-show too!! ng-show works perfectly in this case.

Comment: Yeah right. But still you can use ng-if to be in safer-side, since it won't render the element in DOM window but the ng-show will do that and the user can modify its visiblity through DOM. If you find this answer is fulfils your problem solution, please consider to give up-vote and mark this as answer. :) cheers...